# Improve performance of multiple row insertions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller API method where I insert many rows (around 4000 - 8000), before inserting a new row I also check if a venue with the same ame was added already in the zone sothat's another Elouent call, my issue is I usually get timeout errors becuase the row inserting takes too much, I use set_time_limit(0) but this seems too hacky.

I think the key is the validation check I do before inserting a new row.

```
 //Check if there is a venue with same name and in the same zone already added
             $alreadyAdded = Venue::where('name', $venue['name'])->whereHas('address', function ($query) use ($address){
                $query->where('provinceOrState' , $address['provinceOrState']);
            })->orWhere('venueId',$venue['venueId'])->first();
```

Is there a way I can improve the performance of this method ? This is my complete method call:

```
public function uploadIntoDatabase(Request $request)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $count = 0;

        foreach($request->input('venuesToUpload') as $index => $venue)
        {

             //Check if there is a venue with same name and in the same zone already added
             $alreadyAdded = Venue::where('name', $venue['name'])->whereHas('address', function ($query) use ($address){
                $query->where('provinceOrState' , $address['provinceOrState']);
            })->orWhere('venueId',$venue['venueId'])->first();

            if(!$alreadyAdded)
            {
                $newVenue = new Venue();
                $newVenue->name = $venue['name'];
                $newVenue->save();
                $count++;

               
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $count.' new venues uploaded to database',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: i might break this up into junks, get all the `venuId`s for that chunk, query all of them, then iterate the chunk, if the current iteration wasn't in the `venueId`s returned from the query then do the more complicated query to see if the record exists by those other conditions, would cut down on the selects (assuming the `where` on `venueId` is the condition that is met more than once per chunk), but the inserts could/should be done in bulk

Answer (score 0):

use only one request to add the venues

```php
$newVenues = [];
$count = 0;
foreach($request->input('venuesToUpload') as $index => $venue) {

    //Check if there is a venue with same name and in the same zone already added
    $alreadyAdded = Venue::where('name', $venue['name'])->whereHas('address', function ($query) use ($address){
        $query->where('provinceOrState' , $address['provinceOrState']);
    })->orWhere('venueId',$venue['venueId'])->count();

    if(!$alreadyAdded) {
        $newVenues [] = ['name' => $venur['name'];               
    }
}
if ($newVenues) {
    $count = count($newVenues);
    Venue::insert($newVenues);
}
```

As for the verification part, change the `first` to `count` cause you dont need to recover the data, just the information that it exists. And since you're verifying with both name and id, you can do some custom query that verifies all values in one query using a static table made from the request inputs and joining on the existing venues table where venues.id = null.